# Find a recursive algorithm in Mathematica that deletes duplicates in a list

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to implement an algorithm in Mathematica that deletes duplicates from a given list.
Here's what I've tried:

```
delrec[l___List] := Module[{m = {}},
If[Length[l] != 1,
If[MemberQ[l[[1 ;; Length[l] - 1]], l[[Length[l]]]], 
  delrec[DeleteCases[l[[1 ;; Length[l] - 1]]], 
  delrec[l[[1 ;; Length[l] - 1]]]] ,
 Print[l]];
l
];]
```

However, this code doesn't really work and I'm unsure why. I also need the list to be output in the same order, so the duplicates get removed but the sorting of the list stays the same.
Using DelelteDuplicates or Union is not an option. The function needs to be recursive.

Comment: "DelelteDuplicates or Union is not an option" why not? "needs to be recursive" why?

Comment: Because that's the task I have to complete according to the description of my project. ;)

Comment: I won't do your homework, but I'll give you one hint. Look carefully at `delrec[DeleteCases[l[[1;;Length[l]-1]]],delrec[l[[1;;Length[l]-1]]]]` and carefully count the left and right brackets to see exactly what that is doing. You define `delrec` to accept a single argument. What are you actually giving to that outermost `delrec` there? It might be a little easier to see if you replace `l[[1;;Length[l]-1]]` with `Most[l]` and `l[[Length[l]]]` with `Last[l]` Then I think that becomes `delrec[DeleteCases[Most[l]],delrec[Most[l]]]` Check that carefully to make certain I haven't made any mistake.

Comment: Thanks, the code is now working to remove duplicates at the end of list but unfortunately the duplicates in the middle of a list still stay?

Answer (score 0):

```
DelRek[l___List] := 
 If[Length[l] > 1, 
  Prepend[DelRek[
    If[MemberQ[Drop[l, 1], First[l]], 
     DeleteCases[Drop[l, 1], First[l]], Drop[l, 1]]], First[l]], l]
```

or alternatively

```
DelRek[l___List] := 
 If[Length[l] > 1, 
  Prepend[DelRek[
    DeleteCases[Drop[l, 1], First[l]], First[l]]],
  l]
```